# Groovy HttpBuilder/RESTClient: how to input multiple form parameters of the same name

Tags: rest, groovy, httpbuilder

We have been using Spock to hit endpoints in api tests - up until now, we have been able to use a map to construct a POST body for json endpoints.

But now we have an api with form params, with multiple parameters of the same name. Can't send in a map; can't build a simple Groovy object with 2 duplicate params.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I've used httpbuilder, but I think providing a list as the value works:

```
[name: ['one','two']] // ..?name=one&name=two
```